Chrome browser not calling when Python script is run via Jenkins + Github on Windows local machine
My Python code (Windows machine)
from selenium import webdriver
print("new Line")
print("2 Line")
print("3 Line")
holdChrome = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
holdChrome.add_experimental_option("detach", True)   #Restrict auto close of chrome
e = webdriver.Chrome(holdChrome)
e.get("https://keepr.inoidsolutions.in/")

When I run this Python code on Jenkins + Github it executes all Python code but doesn't launch Chrome browser on it.

When you run a Python script that uses Selenium WebDriver to launch a Chrome browser on a Jenkins server (or any headless CI/CD environment), the Chrome browser won't be visible because Jenkins usually runs in a headless environment (i.e, without a graphical user interface).
What is Headless mode?
Headless mode is a feature of web browsers (like Chrome and Firefox) that allows them to run without a graphical user interface (GUI). This means the browser operates in the background and performs all the usual web interactions, such as navigating to pages, clicking links, and filling out forms, without rendering a visible window. Headless mode is advantageous in automated testing, web scraping, and CI/CD pipelines where a display isn't necessary.
